# RestSharp Azure Web API call fails when adding more parameters

Tags: c#, json, rest, restsharp, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to call an Azure Computer Vision API, specifically [POST] Batch Read File, using RestSharp. Everything is working fine in the code below:

```cs
private void MakeBatchReadRequest(string imageFilePath)
{
    try
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient("https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/");
        client.AddDefaultHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("vision/v2.0/read/core/asyncBatchAnalyze", Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

        byte[] byteData = GetImageAsByteArray(imageFilePath);
        request.AddParameter("application/octet-stream", byteData, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        operationLocation = response.Headers.Where(x => x.Name == "Operation-Location").First.Value;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I didn't have to include the parameter `mode` since according to the API documentation seen [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/2afb498089f74080d7ef85eb), it was optional and the default value was `Printed` which was what I already wanted. However if I add the parameter `mode` (just in case I change my mind and switch to something else) in the request as shown below:

```cs
private void MakeBatchReadRequest(string imageFilePath)
{
    try
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient("https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/");
        client.AddDefaultHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("vision/v2.0/read/core/asyncBatchAnalyze", Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

        byte[] byteData = GetImageAsByteArray(imageFilePath);
        request.AddParameter("application/octet-stream", byteData, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        request.AddParameter("mode", "Printed") // This will cause the web API to return an error response.

        RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        operationLocation = response.Headers.Where(x => x.Name == "Operation-Location").First.Value;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The API returns a response status code `415` and status description `Unsupported Media Type`. The whole JSON response is below:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadArgument",
        "message": "Unsupported media type."
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure how adding a simple parameter to the request could trigger an error response from the API. Also I'm not sure why the error response is `Unsupported Media Type` since I am using a `JPG` image file that is supported and set its content type as `application/octet-stream` in the request.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It worked for me (aside from minor compilation issues).  Is it possible you have a stale version of RestSharp?  I was testing with version 106.6.9 on .NET Core.

Comment: I was using WinForms .Net Framework version 4.5 with RestSharp version 105.2.3. I was aware that the RestSharp version 105.2.3 was the highest possible version for .Net Framework 4.5. Let me try upgrading the versions and then I'll get back to you.

Comment: @cthrash I am pleased to inform you that you were right. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to .Net Framework version 4.6.1 and RestSharp version 106.6.9 and it now works fine. I guess I have no choice but to upgrade my app's .Net Framework version so I could use the newer and less buggy version of RestSharp.

Comment: I should add that if you're not married to RestSharp, Microsoft publishes Swagger-generated .NET Client SDKs for all Cognitive Services properties.  It supports .NET Framework 4.5.2, and have return types expressed in concrete classes.  The Computer Vision pages is [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision).

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks for the tip! :)